# Nuxt3: How to typescript a Proxy Object

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

What is the correct way of typeing a Proxy object? I'm making a v-directive.

My code:

```
export const useProductImpressionTracking = {
  mounted: (el: HTMLElement, binding: any)  => {
    if (binding.value) {
```

I want to set `binding` to a type instead of `any` but if I do that my IDE (webstorm) says that `value` doesn't exist.

The code works, I just want to type it correctly

Comment: `binding: { value: whatevertype }`? Without further context, only people that know Nuxt + TypeScript can help.

Comment: I thought I know Nuxt (Vue), but haven't seen `mounted` with arguments yet. `binding` is a reference to a data object bind to html input via `v-model`?

Comment: @Ellrohir I'm building a v-directive to to track divs coming into view using an intersection observer. So in the template it looks like this:
`<ProductCard v-for="product in shownList" v-track="product" ...` 

`shownList` is a computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/main/types/options.d.ts#L318) of vue2 you can use this interface `DirectiveBinding`

```js
export const useProductImpressionTracking = {
  mounted: (el: HTMLElement, binding: DirectiveBinding)  => {
    if (binding.value) {
```